Compilation and output.lof errors when Figures are inserted
I am currently writing my thesis and all was going well until I reached a chapter that required a lot of pictures and little text. The majority of the pictures were placed next to each other with the original code looking like this:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Fractured X-oriented 15\%]{{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Fractured Y-oriented 15\%]{{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image}}}
    \caption{PLA 15\%}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

And then the next picture right after was just one, with the code:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{image}
        \caption{15\% stress-strain diagram}
    \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

I added around 20 pictures like this and I've been getting too many output.lof error messages. I tried to fix it by removing things like the % but the error remains. I used the code above in other chapters too with no errors but it was just once or twice.
The error I'm getting is "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." In my class I have the graphicx package and then the path for the pictures.
Even if I delete the whole chapter/the picture folder or clear my cache and recompile, it seems as if the error gets carried like the code still exists.
Does anyone know how to fix it? I can provide further info if needed.

Weclome. // AFAIK you shouldn't use [width=0.5\linewidth] , but make it a narrower AND change it like this: [width=0.48\textwidth]   . // Also, even here, you should add code that compiles. Though we certainly can't reproduce this specific problem, the preamble almost always is relevant.

do not restrict the float placements with [ht]. Allow LaTeX to build float pages. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

@UlrikeFischer as far as i'm understanding you're saying to first delete all placements and then see which can go where and add necessary placements accoriding to what latex can produce?

yes, placements restrict floats and if you are unlucky  LaTeX can't place them at all and is unhappy.

@UlrikeFischer thank you for your answers and the help. However even if i delete all placements the problem still remains. Ive deleted my cache files too. It's almost as if everything is still there if that makes sense

Show the actual error message (the first if you more than one)

@UlrikeFischer this is the first error shown
l.34 ...ering   X-oriented 15% }
}}{29}{subfigure.5.1}%
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in $x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in \hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
i've deleted the % in the caption and still nothing
